# How to stop HTML injection when using template literals

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple CRUD webapp that's built upon populating template literals based on user input. The issue is that if the user inputs something like `<b>Hey</b>` then it's rendered as bold on the page:

```js
const element = (name) => {
  const elementHTML= 
            `<div>
              <ul>
                <li>${name}</li>
              </ul>
            </div>`
  const element = document.createElement('div')
  element.innerHTML = elementHTML
  return element.firstChild
}

const userInput = '<b>foo</b>'
document.body.appendChild(element(userInput)) //
```

How can I stop this interaction? My guess is to use some invisible character around the `${embedded expression}` to stop what's inside from being interpreted as HTML, so something like:

`` const elementhtml = `<div>|${name}|</div>` `` 
Where `|` would be the invisible character.

Is there a best practice to draw the expressions as text instead of HTML? I understand that this is a product of using innerHTML to create the element, but isn't that necessary to make use of template literals?

Answer (score 1):

Don't interpolate input from the user into HTML markup directly. Either escape the entities so they're interpreted as plain text instead of HTML tags, or assign to the `.textContent` of the element instead.

```js
const element = (name) => {
  const elementHTML= 
            `<div>
              <ul>
                <li></li>
              </ul>
            </div>`
  const element = document.createElement('div')
  element.innerHTML = elementHTML
  element.querySelector('li').textContent = name;
  return element.firstChild
}

const userInput = '<b>foo</b>'
document.body.appendChild(element(userInput))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `.replace()` `<` and `>` with unicode HTML entities `&lt;` and `&gt;`, respectively.

```js
const element = (name) => {
  const elementHTML =
    `<div>
              <ul>
                <li>${name}</li>
              </ul>
            </div>`;
  const element = document.createElement('div');
  element.innerHTML = elementHTML;
  return element.firstChild;
}

const userInput = (data) => data.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
document.body.appendChild(element(userInput(`<b>foo</b>`)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the same you did but don't mention it directly in the li tag. Do it this way:
document.getElementById("li").innerText=name

Answer (score 0):

I see you are getting `name` from the user. You can validate the `name` to be a real name first, so you don't need to think of the `HTML`. This `Regular Expression` can be used to validate a name.

`/^[a-z ]+$/i` characters from a-z case insensitive, and spaces are allowed. Meaning the user cannot put html tags in there.

Even if you have validated user input, you should still not use `innerHTML` as it will take the `name` or `text` as `html`. You should instead use `innerText` or `textContent` to prevent that.

You can also you `replace()` and  `replaceAll()` methods to remove parts of the text, this could be the `html` or any other tags inside the `text`